.NET SDK installation not found on macOS Sequoia
I am trying to install .NET 8.0.4 SDK on my macOS. The installation succeeds but nothing is found in /usrs/local/share. I’ve tried installing the Arm64 and x64 versions. dotnet -—list-sdks returns nothing
dotnet —info returns “no sdks found”. Any other ideas? All I can find it how to set the environmental path after a successful install. The folder doesn’t even exist for me.
Trying to install the .NET core extensions through VS fails with error: One or more errors occurred. (A server with the specified hostname could not be found.)

I actually have the same problem. I installed the new version on Sequoia, but it's still showing up as .NET 7.
Dis you find a solution.
I just found this
https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/324

you could go to
.net8 installation link
after the installation success try to
dotnet --version

